# Lenovo ideaPad 110 AMD a9 7th gen black screen

Tags: windows-10, battery, lenovo-laptop

I'm facing black screen issue on my laptop. I've tried:-

1. Holding the power key for 30 seconds when the charger was connected as well as disconnected.
2. Removing the battery and holding power key for 30 seconds when the charger was connected as well as disconnected.
3. Holding shift +f8 before pressing and releasing the power button from the turned off state.
4. Spamming f2 key while holding fn after pressing the power button to start the laptop.

None of these work. I couldn't locate the CMOS battery on this so I couldn't disconnect that. Upon starting I don't even see the Lenovo logo.

I've noticed that the fan doesn't turn on but the LED lights do for both battery and power.

Using Windows 10.

Thank you for reading so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try Press Novo button to enter Novo Boot Menu, select BIOS Setup to enter BIOS.

Comment: We need more info regarding your problem.
When did your problem start and how (eg did you make any modifications to the computer that required disassemble such as RAM or HDD replacement.)
**If not** my first recommendation since your computer doesn't seem to POST properly,is try using an external monitor during boot so you can see if it's a monitor-related problem or dGPU/iGPU or sth else gone wrong (eg BIOS update maybe?)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, David. Unfortunately pressing that button just turns on the LED like the power button does.

Comment: I'll try the monitor thingy now. Although I didn't do anything which would cause any modification or something. The laptop was last turned on the night before yesterday when I and my pal were playing a game on LAN.